# XCode 5 Core Data Model Crashes

Tags: xcode, core-data

I am using `XCode5-DP3` and `OSX Mavericks` on my MacBook Pro, I know that XCode 5 is still a beta version, but Core Data Model is bugging me all the time. Everytime I try to open a Core Data Model file, `XCode 5` shows it for 1 second and crashes. The same project and file works fine with `XCode 4`.

I searched a lot and didn't find answer, Apple doesn't mention it in release notes either. I found someone [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4695307/xcode-crashes-when-trying-to-view-an-xcdatamodel) is having the same issue for `XCode 4`, but I don't think it's because y Core Data Model file, and I tried open it as a raw text file but I got nothing. Is there anyway to resolve this issue?

Comment: Yes. [File a bug](http://bugreport.apple.com/) and hope that it will be fixed in DP4.

Comment: Known bug, apparently. That's what they told me anyway.

Comment: Okay, thanks, I'm just using XCode 4 to edit my data model now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It have been fixed in Xcode5-DP4.